# Can an angular 2 component be used with an attribute selector?

Tags: angular

We currently have an existing small Angular 1 project that is used in an on premises Sharepoint 2013 environment. For a large part of our content, we use publishing pages on the Sharepoint environment.

With Angular 1, we could define directives to be restricted to: *match attribute name, tag name, comments, or class name*. Most of the directives we created were attribute or tag name. The preference would have been tag name, but the publishing platform on Sharepoint strips out **unknown** elements. So that means we were left with using attributes in order to bring our directives in to the publishing pages. With Angular 2 though, I've only seen components implemented by tag name.

Is it possible with Angular 2 to use attribute names in order to use our components? This is a requirement for us because of the restrictions in the Sharepoint publishing platform.

Thanks.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Yes, the `selector` property of the `@Component` decorator is a [**CSS selector**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors) (or a subset of):

> **`selector`:** `'.cool-button:not(a)'`
>
> Specifies a CSS selector that identifies this directive within a template.
>   Supported selectors include `element`, `[attribute]`, `.class`, and `:not()`.
>   Does *not* support parent-child relationship selectors.
>
> <sub>**Source:** [Angular Cheat Sheet / Directive Configuration](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/cheatsheet.html), which `@Component` inherits.</sub>

That way you can use `[name-of-the-attribute]` (namely, the [CSS attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)), such as:

```
@Component({
    selector: "[other-attr]",
    ...
})
export class OtherAttrComponent {
```

Se [**demo plunker here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/SVbMLQJSrZMkiwf5NKc8?p=preview).

The usual way is the [CSS type (AKA element or tag) selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Type_selectors):

```
@Component({
    selector: "some-tag",
    ...
})
```

And it matches a tag with name `some-tag`.

You can even have a component that matches [both a tag or an attribute](http://webdesign.about.com/od/cssselectors/f/comma-in-css-selectors.htm):

```
@Component({
    selector: "other-both,[other-both]",
    template: `this is other-both ({{ value }})`
})
export class OtherBothComponent {
```

[Demo plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SVbMLQJSrZMkiwf5NKc8?p=preview) contains examples of all three.

> ## Is `[attributeName="attributeValue"]` supported?

Yes. But mind the quotes. In the current implementation, the selector `[attributeName="attributeValue"]` actually matches `<sometag attributeName='"attributeValue"'>`, so test around before committing to this approach.

Comment: Note: since any CSS selector is valid, you could even use class selectors such as `selector: '.my-class-name',` which would match any elements with such class.

Comment: Great. thanks. I didn't see any reference to being able to pull this off when going through the Angular 2 site. So glad this is possible.

Comment: is `[attributeName="attributeValue"]` supported?

Comment: @BradKent Yes. But mind the quotes. The selector `[attributeName="attributeValue"]` actually matches `<sometag attributeName='"attributeValue"'>`

Comment: The linter that comes with Angular CLI complains about components as attributes. Is there a way to disable that rule on a per file basis?

Comment: @Votemike I haven't found a way to disable the error but if you add an element selector, in addition to the attribute selector, the error goes away. e.g., `selector: "my-selector,[my-selector]"`

Answer (score 13):

Selector property of @Component decorator support, element selector, attribute selector and class selector:

**1. Element selector:**

```
@Component({
 selector: 'app-servers'
})
```

**Usage:** `<app-servers></app-servers>`

**2. Attribute selector:**

```
@Component({
 selector: '[app-servers]'
})
```

**Usage:** `<div app-servers></div>`

**3. Class selector:**

```
@Component({
 selector: '.app-servers'
})
```

**Usage:** `<div class="app-servers"></div>`

**Note:** Angular 2 does not support id and pseudo selectors

Answer (score 10):

Yes, according to this https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/cheatsheet.html (Components and Directives are very similar in general). Instead of using element selector:

```
selector: 'custom-element-name'
```

Use:

```
selector: '[custom-attribute-name]'
```

And in your parent component's template:

```
<div custom-attribute-name></div>
```

Answer (score 7):

Absolutely. Essentially this is just a CSS selector, so if you need to use attribute you just do this:

```
@Component({
    selector: "my-tag[with-my-attribute]"
})
```

Comment: And that would be selected by:
`<my-tag with-my-attribute></my-tag>` 
but not by
`<my-tag></my-tag>`
Correct?