# Can't bind to 'character' since it isn't a known property of 'tr'

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps

*Import*, variable *declaration* done. Still throws error.
Also read older issues on SO.

**app.module.ts:**

```
import { HotelTableComponent } from './hotel-table/hotel-table.component';
import { HotelTableRowComponent } from './hotel-table-row/hotel-table-row.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HotelTableComponent,
    HotelTableRowComponent
  ],
```

**hotel-table-row.component.ts:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-hotel-table-row',
  .....

export class HotelTableRowComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() character: any;
  @Input() columns: string[];
```

**hotel-table.component.html:**

```
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th *ngFor="let c of columns">{{c}}</th>
    </tr>

    <tr *ngFor="let ch of characters | async" 
    app-hotel-table-row
    [character]="ch" 
    [columns]="columns">
    </tr>

  </table>
```

**Console:**

```
compiler.js:215 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'character' since it isn't a known property of 'tr'. ("
    <tr *ngFor="let ch of characters | async" 
    app-hotel-table-row
    [ERROR ->][character]="ch" 
    [columns]="columns">
    </tr>
"): ng:///AppModule/HotelTableComponent.html@7:4
Can't bind to 'columns' since it isn't a known property of 'tr'. ("
    app-hotel-table-row
    [character]="ch" 
    [ERROR ->][columns]="columns">
    </tr>

"): ng:///AppModule/HotelTableComponent.html@8:4
```

Comment: What selector are you using for HotelTableRowComponent?

Comment: selector: 'app-hotel-table-row',

Comment: try `[app-hotel-table-row]`

Comment: where to write this?

Comment: instead of your current selector. It should be `selector: '[app-hotel-table-row]'`

Comment: IT WorKED! But my lint cries for using squate braces. Why do i need to use it in this case?

Comment: Because component selector is actual CSS selector and in CSS to select attribute by name you have to put it in square brackets.

Comment: do we have any other option to by-pass this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to bind your component to an attribute you need to put component name in square brackets because component selector is actual CSS selector and in CSS to select attribute by name you have to put it in square brackets. Try this

```
selector: '[app-hotel-table-row]'
```

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38471827/can-an-angular-2-component-be-used-with-an-attribute-selector) post for more details.

Comment: Thanks. It works. Please include you last comment in the answer. It will be helpful for others