# Angular attribute component with value

Tags: angular, typescript, components

Using Angular `6.0.7`, I am creating an attribute component and injecting a value into it. For this I am following the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38471827/can-an-angular-2-component-be-used-with-an-attribute-selector?rq=1).

I want to know if there is a way, just like in AngularJS, to input a value directly into the component, without the need to define a separate `[form]=""`. 
For example: `<div my-component="form">`.

---

**The html**

```
<form (ngSubmit)="login(loginForm.form.valid)" 
      #loginForm="ngForm"
      validate-on-submit='"loginForm"'>
</form>
```

---

**The attribute component**

```
@Component({
  selector: '[validate-on-submit="form"]',
  template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`
})
export class ValidateOnSubmitComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() private form: NgForm;

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    console.warn(this.form);    
  }
}
```

The `console.warn(this.form)` results in '`undefined`'.

---

**What I am trying to do**

I am trying to Inject my form (via the variable `#loginForm`) into the component, but I do not want to make an other binding, like `[form]="loginForm"`. According to the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38471827/can-an-angular-2-component-be-used-with-an-attribute-selector?rq=1) this should be possible, but I cannot make it to work. Has this changed since a higher Angular version or am I doing something wrong here?

---

**I have tried**

I have tried to bind the input to the `@Input` variable via explicit binding, `@Input('form') private form: NgForm`, but this alo resulted in '`undefined`'.

I also tried to revert or change the quotes `validate-on-submit="loginForm"` or `validate-on-submit="'loginForm'"`, but in some of the tries this results in Angular not reconizing the component selector at all.

---

**Solution**

With the answer of @user184994 I've managed to change my code and get it working. This resulted in the following code:

*html*

```
<form (ngSubmit)="login(loginForm.form.valid)" 
      #loginForm="ngForm"
      [validate-on-submit]="loginForm">
</form>
```

*component*

```
@Directive({
  selector: "[validate-on-submit]"
})
export class ValidateOnSubmitComponent {

  @Input("validate-on-submit") private form: NgForm;
}
```

Note that the selector is surrounded with `[]` for indicating that it is an Angular directive and you are injecting something and there reference to `@Input("validate-on-submit")`, since a property cannot have dashes in it's name.

Also note that i've change the `@Component` decorator to `@Directive`, since it won't be doing any DOM manipulation it is not necessary to have a view. [More info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32680244/directive-v-s-component-in-angular?rq=1).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to create an input with the same name as the attribute selector. For example,

```
@Component({
  selector: '[hello]',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}!</h1>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent  {

  @Input() hello: string;

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.hello);
  }
}
```

I can use this like `<div hello="Test" ></div>`, and the value `Test` will be passed in.

Working example [here.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2schec?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

[You Solution here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5epekr)

HTML:

app.component.html

```
<form (ngSubmit)="login()"
      #loginForm="ngForm"
      validateonsubmit ="{{loginForm.valid}}" >
</form>
```

hello.component.html:

```
form is valid : {{validateonsubmit}}
```

TS:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import {NgForm } from '@angular/forms'

@Component({
  selector: '[validateonsubmit]',
  templateUrl:'./hello.component.html',
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent  {
  @Input() validateonsubmit : NgForm;

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    console.warn(this.validateonsubmit);    
  }

  login(bool){
    console.log(bool);
  }
}
```